# How can I use an AngularJS filter to select rows from a range?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to filter rows returned and having a problem.

I have the following:

```
    <tr 
    data-ng-show="grid.data.length > 0" 
    data-ng-repeat="row in grid.data | filter:isProblemIdInRange>
       <td>{{ row.problemId }}</td>
```

In my controller I have:

```
    $scope.isProblemIdInRange = function (row) {
        return row.problemId >= $scope.lower && row.problemId < $scope.upper;
    };
```

I have input fields:

```
     <input type="text" data-ng-model="$scope.lower" />
     <input type="text" data-ng-model="$scope.upper" />
```

My problem is that whatever I enter into the two inputs there is nothing that comes back. When I remove the filter then all is okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `$scope`

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="lower" />
<input type="text" data-ng-model="upper" />
```